# Other backgrounds for tty consoles?

Tags: tty, colors

I have in `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ "$TERM" = "linux" ]; then
    echo -en "\e]P0232323" #black
    echo -en "\e]P82B2B2B" #darkgrey
    echo -en "\e]P1D75F5F" #darkred
    echo -en "\e]P9E33636" #red
    echo -en "\e]P287AF5F" #darkgreen
    echo -en "\e]PA98E34D" #green
    echo -en "\e]P3D7AF87" #brown
    echo -en "\e]PBFFD75F" #yellow
    echo -en "\e]P48787AF" #darkblue
    echo -en "\e]PC7373C9" #blue
    echo -en "\e]P5BD53A5" #darkmagenta
    echo -en "\e]PDD633B2" #magenta
    echo -en "\e]P65FAFAF" #darkcyan
    echo -en "\e]PE44C9C9" #cyan
    echo -en "\e]P7E5E5E5" #lightgrey
    echo -en "\e]PFFFFFFF" #white
    clear #for background artifacting
fi
```

How can I choose a certain color?

Answer (score 2):

The command "setterm" can be used to change the background color of consoles. There are many parameters that can be changed. Try this to get started:

```
setterm -background red
clear
```

Then have a look at `man setterm` to see what else you can play with.

Comment: for whatever reason exists this color table?

Can I cause setterm to use "dark gray"="\e]P82B2B2B" from this color chart?

To me the meaning of this color chart absolutely unclear. Why do I need this?

Thanks for hints, Werner.